# Is there a difference between static const int and const int?

Tags: c++, c, static, constants

Is there a difference between `const int` with the preceded class qualifier of `const`  (`static const int`) and `const int` or is it the same?

If it isn´t equivalent,

Why should I explicitly make a `const` variable also `static`?

Comment: I think the one only difference is the linkage

Comment: Look at the generated assembly language.  Could be different.